# How can I position text relative to axes in altair?

Tags: python, altair

I'm trying to make a graph much like the [Multi-Line Tooltip Example](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/multiline_tooltip.html). However I want to make two modifications. 
First of all, I want to be able to zoom in to a portion of the data. I fixed that using `alt.selection(type="interval", encodings=["x"], bind="scales")` and a transform_filter. So far no problem.
The problem is that the text labels near the points are overlapping because the lines are close together. Therefore I would like to move the labels to a fixed position within the axes along the top. Is it possible to put the labels at a fixed position within the axes, even when zooming in on the graph (see mockups below)? The problem is that when you zoom in both the x and the y domains change, so the positions of the labels should be expressed as a fraction of the domains.

Another solution I could accept is when the selected value is appended to the legend labels, or some other label outside the plot area.

Mock up of the full view:
[image: Full view]

Mock up of the zoomed view:
[image: Zoomed view]

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57272629/how-can-i-position-text-relative-to-axes-in-altair

Comment: That link points to this page, did you perhaps mean to link to another page?

Answer (score 2):

You can control the text position with the x and y encodings. Here is an example of placing text at the top of the axis:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.arange(1, 21),
    'y': np.random.randint(0, 20, 20),
})

points = alt.Chart(data).mark_point().encode(
    x='x',
    y='y'
)

text = points.mark_text(baseline='top').encode(
    y=alt.value(0),  # pixels from top
    text='y'
)

points + text
```

[image]

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself well enough, so I expanded the question a little bit with two mockups of the expected result. This answer explains how to fix the y position, but not the x.

Comment: If you're going to change your question this substantially after it's already been answered, please in the future just ask a new question.