# How to get column values added along with y axis in altair graph

Tags: python, altair

I have a horizontal bar graph and I need to add values from 1 column of the data frame parallel to the y axis. How do I get that in Altair?

Comment: Could you include some sample code of what you have tried or an image of the end result you want? You can start from one of the examples in the Altair gallery.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the code with the understanding that the intent of your question is to position the label in parallel with the y-axis in a horizontal bar chart. The key is how to register the data that determines the placement of the labels. I referred to [this](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/bar_chart_with_labels.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57272629/how-can-i-position-text-relative-to-axes-in-altair).

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.wheat()

bars = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='wheat:Q',
    y="year:O"
)

text = bars.mark_text(
    align='left',
    baseline='middle',
    dx=10, # update
    color='white'
).encode(
    x=alt.value(0), # update
    text='wheat:Q',
)

(bars + text).properties(height=900)
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer and give it 1+, thanks!